# Boosting ranked lists

Tags: machine-learning

Suppose 10 people conduct a 10 studies which rank people's top five favorite colors. For instance, one survey may produce a list 1) red 2) blue 3) green 4) yellow 5) orange, where red is the favorite color on the list and orange is the least favorite on the list.

The methodology of the 10 surveys are completely different, and each one has its own weakness. For instance, one survey may look at the color of people's clothes and assume that people like to wear their favorite color, while another survey may ask people to tell them their favorite color without asking any more questions about their second, third, forth, or fifth favorite color.

Is there a known good "boosting" algorithm for combining the 10 surveys to get one very good ranking that combines the strengths of each survey?

Comment: You might find the material and references here useful: http://lingpipe-blog.com/2011/06/23/steyvers-lee-miller-hemmer-2009-wisdom-of-crowds-recollection-order-information/

Comment: You want to build a classifier or simply combine few surveys? In the latter case this has nothing to do with boosting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [AdaRank](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.5.7086&rep=rep1&type=pdf) or [RankBoost](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/hangli/xu-sigir07.pdf).

Both algorithms attempt to build strong ranker as a linear combination of weak ones in a traditional AdaBoost-like manner. RankBoost tries to minimize the number of swapped pairs, while AdaRank minimizes ranking performance measures (such as NDCG or MAP) directly. According to AdaRank paper, second approach is better and AdaRank outperforms RankBoost.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit? Like write few-word intro to those algorithms?